# How can I mix worker queues with pub/sub

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm doing some research if rabbitMQ is the way to go for me.

Can I mix publish/subscribe and worker queues?
[image]

The goal is to have have a few queues which holds items of for specific process.
Each process can have a lot of workers.

Answer (score 0):

The setup shown in this diagram is possible. If the exchange `X` is a `direct` or `topic` exchange, the '*specific process*' would be represented by one of the two queues and routing of messages would be based on the routing key or topic of a message.

Consumers ('*workers*') would consume messages from the queues using round-robin.